# Break out of a recursive function when condition met

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, exception, depth-first-search

I am trying to build a simple cycle detection algorithm using depth-first search (DFS). The algorithm works as follows: perform DFS on some node (for the moment just assume the whole graph is connected) and mark any node gray that's currently being used, and black if it's done. If a current node has a gray neighbor, exit the function and print "Cycle detected"

Here's my code, with a simple 4 node graph

```
from collections import defaultdict
G = {'F': ['X', 'O'], 'X': ['F', 'F'],'O':[]}
V = set(G.keys())
gray, black = set(), []
def dfs(u):
    try:
        print('-'*30,"\n",u)
        gray.add(u)
        for v in G[u]:
            if v in gray:
                raise ValueError
            elif v not in black:
                dfs(v)
        gray.discard(u)
        black.append(u)
    except:
        return True
if dfs('F'):
    print('Cycle detected')
```

I thought the try except would work, but it does not.

Lastly, I am aware that I can use a mutable variable like cycle = [False] and update this to true if my condition is met. I am asking how to avoid doing this! Thanks!

Comment: In this case, just “return” from the termination case. If that doesn’t work, then the algorithm implementation is likely flawed. The try..except appears unnecessary and adding it over a “return” shouldn’t change or fix a broken algorithm implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm isn't broken. It can be fixed as follows:

remove the try, except pattern and instead replace the loop over adj vertices with

```
for v in G[u]:
    if v in gray:
        return True
    elif v not in black:
        if dfs(v):
            return True
```

dfs(v) in the if does double duty, opening the recursive call and retrieving its output. Since this return is in the outermost recursion and comes after the aforementioned return statement, when the innermost recursion returns True, it will automatically cut off further searching and return true as well.